# Acessar a variável de um accordion de um componente filho para o pai

Tags: angular

Eu preciso acessar de um componente filho o expansor do accordion que se encontra no componente pai, o nome dele é **isExpandend**

No componente filho, ao clicar no botão salvar, ele deve incluir um novo serviço, e expandir o accordion onde foi adicionado esse serviço novo.

No componente pai eu já uso o isExpandend para filtrar os serviços e expandir o accordion.

**Esse é o código do Pai HTML**

```
<mat-accordion class="agregador-pesquisa__accordion mat-accordion" [multi]="isExpanded">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-expansion-panel" mat-expanded="true"
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion
```

**Componente Pai TS**

```
public isExpanded: boolean;
```

OBS: Coloquei só um trecho do código pra facilitar o entendimento. Só quero saber se é possível acessar a variável isExpanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível usando **@Input** e **@Output**. Como neste exemplo, [retirado da documentação:](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

**Componente filho - TS:**

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ItemOutputComponent {
  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(value: string) {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

**Componente pai - TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

  addItem(newItem: string) {
    this.items.push(newItem);
  }
}
```

**Componente pai - TEMPLATE:**

```
<app-item-output (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></app-item-output>
```

Comment: Então no caso  ficaria  (newItemEvent)="isExpanded($event)". Com isso eu poderia manipular da forma que eu quiser o isExapnded usando Output, né ?

Comment: Na verdade o `addItem` precisa ser um método, e ele atualizar a propriedade `isExpanded`.

Comment: Por exemplo, no componente pai, crie o método `updateExpanded(val: string) { this.isExpanded = val }`. E no template ficaria `(newItemEvent)="updateExpanded($event)`

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado !!